# is #define in C similar to a static variable in Java?

Tags: java, c, variables, static

In C we can write:

```
#define LOWER 0
```

And in Java we can write:

```
static int lower = 0;
```

Don't these statements have the same purpose of letting other methods use the variable lower?

Answer (score 4):

They are totally different.  Define is more of a copy paste that the C preprocessor uses.  Static is an attribute modifier for a Java class.  A static attribute can be changed at runtime.

Comment: It is important to note that there will be a similar copy-paste when using `static final` (with a compile-time constant).

Comment: This may or may not be true.  Static final attributes can be assigned in static blocks, which are executed when the class is loaded by a class loader. For this simple example, it would function the same though.

Comment: I'm referring to cases like `public static final int a = 42;`.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` in C causes textual substitution. For example:

```
#define PI 3.14

...
a = PI * r * r;  // becomes: a = 3.14 * r * r
```

Now, the scope of `#define` is much larger than that; it isn't only limited to variables (and there isn't something directly equivalent in Java). When you have a `static` variable, there is no guarantee that that variable will not change, so a similar "textual substation" cannot be made. *However*, when you declare a `static final` variable and assign it to a [compile-time constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), there *is* such a guarantee. So:

```
public static final double PI = 3.14;

...
a = PI * r * r;  // becomes: a = 3.14 * r * r, like in C
```

Much like what happened with `#define`, static final constants are replaced with their actual values at compile time. In this sense, static final constants are similar to `#define` constants.

Comment: It may be good to show why textual substitution may not always yield expected results.  For example, `#define PAGE_WIDTH 8.5`, `#define PRINT_WIDTH PAGE_WIDTH-3`, `double center = PRINT_WIDTH/2;` would define `center` to be `8.5-3/2`, i.e. `7.5`.

Answer (score 0):

**static**, no.

**final**, yes.

```
final int LOWER = 0;
```

A `final` variable can only be initialized once.

`static` variables belong to class, rather than an instance.

*HOWEVER*

They may be similar in function, however the way the operate is completely different.

A final variable is still just that, a variable. A `#define` in C(++), is actually interpreted at build, and modifys the binary output accordingly, causing the vales to be constants at runtime.

`#define` is more efficient.

Comment: I generally see both static and final, often in a separate constants class. `class Constants { public static final int Lower = 0; }`

Comment: How can you tell that define is more efficient? In c++ shouldn't one go for  `const` like variables?

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is a preprocessor directive - the value you define gets swapped into wherever it is mentioned in the code before compilation. It has a number of [pitfalls](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-cpp-en-4/macro-pitfalls.html) though - like any global variable, it can conflict with a similarly named variable somewhere else (among other things).

If you want a constant, use `const` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many places (e.g. array dimensions) where compile-time constant expressions may be used but `const`-declared globals cannot.  The only C constructs which behave semantically as constants are constant literals expressions or `enum` values, and the latter are limited to things expressible as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The big advantage of the Java `final int LOWER=0;` definition is that LOWER always remains a variable, and will be visible as such to the debugger.

In C, the defined value is substituted by the precompiler in the code and the constant name is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The No. first advice from C to C++ is: 'do not use #define', try to use a constant variable instead.  '#define' is difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

in `#define lower 0` lower is not a variable. At compile time, `lower` would be replaced by `0` where ever it is used in an entire code.

whereas `static int lower = 0;` defines a variable and actual memory reference would be done at runtime to access the value of a variable. Plus value of this can be changed in your code.

to avoid changes you can define it like this `static final int lower = 0;`

compilers now a days are doing pretty much good job in optimization. So at compile time only this `lower` will be replaced by `0`.

So you can only "say" that `#define lower 0` in C is equivalent to `static final int lower = 0;` But they are not the same. Because the later one was replaced while optimization phase. If optimization is off, it will not be replaced at compilation time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The define preprocessor is great for naming constants, but that does not provide the same type checking that a Java (or C++) constant declaration allows.  Having been a C and C++ developer for many years, I really like the type checking which C++ (and Java) provide.  Reminiscent of design by contract, etc.

But the flexibility of languages such as Perl, Python, and Ruby, which offer 'duck typing', and a less rigorous approach to type declarations, also holds merit.  The philosophical discipline offered by rigorous type check has merit.  But when you are just trying to declare a (named) const(ant), all the rigor seems overblown.

So, yes, a #define is one way to spell 'constant'.

```
#define PIE (3.142) //C preprocessor
float PIE_() { return 3.142; } //C also
const float PIE = 3.142; //C++ const
public static final float PIE = 3.142; //Java
PIE = 3.142 #Ruby makes variables with initial capital constant
PIE = 3.142 #Python doesn't really have constants
#Perl is harder, you really have a hard time defining constants
sub PIE { 3.142; }
```

But read about how hard it really is to make a variable constant in Python.
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/?in=user-97991